# How to convert 64-bit to double decimal in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

Using Python, how can I get the decimal floating-point value out from a 64-bit bit pattern?  I think I need to use `struct`, but how can I get it right? Here is what I have tried:

```
struct.unpack('<d','0100000011111000011010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000')

error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from numpy import * #for Double data type
double(int('0100000011111000011010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000',2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int_data = int('0100000011111000011010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000',2)
double_data = struct.unpack('d', struct.pack('q', int_data))[0]
```